# Attribute user.grade cannot be referenced in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance

I have some code for a website that I'm building.

in my `views.py`, i have the following code:

```
                    from django.shortcuts import render
                    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
                    from django.conf.urls import url
                    from .models import UserInfo, Events
                    from django import forms
                    from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, OrderForm
                    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
                    from django.shortcuts import redirect
                    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
                    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
                    # Create your views here.

                    def home(request):
                        return render(request, 'student/index.html')

                    @csrf_exempt
                    def signin(request):
                        print "login"
                        if request.method == 'POST':
                            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                            username = request.POST['username']
                            password = request.POST['password']
                            print "input username ", username
                            try:
                                if form.is_valid():
                                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                                    if user is not None:
                                        print "user not none"
                                        print user.username
                                        print user.email
                                        login(request,user)
                                        return redirect("/")
                                    else:
                                        print "login failed"
                                        raise forms.ValidationError({'username':['Invalid username/password']})
                                else:
                                    print form.errors
                            except:
                                raise


                        else:
                            print "hello"
                            form = LoginForm()

                        return render(request, 'student/login.html', {'form': form})

                    @csrf_exempt
                    def signup(request):
                        print "signup"
                        if request.method == 'POST':
                            print "post signup"
                            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
                            try:
                                if form.is_valid():
                                    print form.cleaned_data
                                    u = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['emailid'], form.cleaned_data['emailid'], form.cleaned_data['passwd1'] )

                                    ui = UserInfo()
                                    ui.user = u
                                    ui.class_of = form.cleaned_data['gradyear']
                                    ui.grade = form.cleaned_data['grade']
                                    ui.balance = 0

                                    ui.save()
                                    user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['emailid'], password=form.cleaned_data['passwd1'])
                                    login(request,user)
                                    print "after login in signup"
                                    return redirect("/")


                                else:
                                    print "error"
                                    print form.errors
                            except:
                                raise
                                print "error here"
                                print form.errors
                                pass
                                #return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})

                        else:
                            form = RegisterForm()

                        return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})

                    def forgotpassword(request):
                        if request.method == 'POST':
                            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                            if form.is_valid():
                                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
                                # ...
                                # redirect to a new URL:

                                print form.cleaned_data
                                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
                            else:
                                print "INVALID"
                                print form.errors
                        else:
                             form = LoginForm()
                        return render(request, 'student/forgotpassword.html')


                    def studentinfo(request):
                        return render(request, 'student/studentinfo.html', {} )

                    def error(request):
                        return render(request, 'student/LoginError.html', {} )

                    def site_logout(request):
                        logout(request)
                        return redirect("/")
                        #return render(request, 'student/studentinfo.html', {} )

                    def order(request):
                        if request.method == 'POST':
                            form = 0
                        return render(request, 'student/orderform.html')

                    def dashboard(request):
                        user = request.user
                        return render(request, 'student/dashboard.html', {'user': user})

                    def blog(request):
                        return render(request, 'student/blog.html')
```

and this is my `models.py`, where `UserInfo` is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class_of = models.IntegerField()
    #username = user.username
    #fname = user.first_name
    #lname = user.last_name
    #email = user.email
    #Staff = user.is_staff
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

class Events(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 80)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)
# Create your models here.
```

in my HTML code using the Django template language, `{{ user.username }}` and `{{ user.email }}` show up perfectly, but why won't `{{ user.grade }}` work the same way?

Comment: Which view is being called by you in this case? Giving us all your views code is useless if we don't have context on the application of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grade` is not an attribute of Django's `User` model but is an attribute of `UserInfo`, you need need to use something like:

```
{{ user.user_infos.grade }}
```

Where `user_infos` is the related_name in your model (it should be `OneToOneField` right?):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_infos')
```

Comment: No trouble :) @doniyor

Comment: where would I add this? in my models.py? @doniyor

Comment: @AbhishekPatel yes, in your models, you just replace the the `user = .. ` line in your userinfo model with the one above, and of course `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: Thanks so much! I want to do this for fname, which is commented out. But when i uncomment it, it says " 'OnetoOneField' object has no attribute 'first_name' " How do i fix this? @doniyor

Comment: @AbhishekPatel you cannot do `fname = user.first_name` in your model definition. and you even  dont need it, since you can get the firstname via user.first_name always

Comment: And i think name is part of the User class, and everything can be called from that class except the name (username and email work)

Comment: @doniyor thats the problem, user.first_name doesnt output anything

Comment: @AbhishekPatel because you still have `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` if you change to OneToOneField, then it should work